# Why do I keep getting the AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Student' when running my program

Tags: python-3.x, attributeerror

I am trying to run a program that implements Object Oriented Programming to help a student register for a course. I keep running into an Attribute Error and can't seem to figure out where my code went wrong.

I initially thought it had something to do with the fact that I had not implemented the self parameter in all the method def statements. But after I fixed this, I still encountered the same error message.

```
ONE = 1
TWO = 2
THREE = 3
FOUR = 4
FIVE = 5

TRUE = True
FALSE = False

COURSES_INPUT = 'courses-sample.txt'
STUDENTS_INPUT= 'students-sample.txt'

import student
import course 



def main():

    process_students()
    process_courses()
    option = get_option()
    while option != 5:
        if option == 1:

            course_num = input('please input course number of course you wish to add: ')
            add_course = new_student.add_course(course_num)
            while add_course == FALSE:
                print('The course requested for add does not exist. Please Try Again.')
                course_num = input('Please input course number of course you wish to add: ')
            if new_course.space_available() == TRUE:
                new_course.enroll_student()
            else:
                print('Class requested does not have any seats available.')

        if option == 2:
            course_num = input('please input course number of course you wish to drop: ')
            drop_course = new_student.drop_course(course_num)
            while drop_course == FALSE:
                print('The enrolled course requested for drop does not exist. Please Try Again.')
                course_num = input('Please input course number of course you wish to drop: ')
            new_course.drop_student()

        if option == 3:
            print_student_info(student_dict)
        if option == 4:
            print_course_schedule(course_dict)
        option = get_option()
    write_updated('students-updated.txt',student_dict)
    write_updated('courses-updated.txt',course_dict)



def print_menu():
    print("1. Add course")
    print("2. Drop course")
    print("3. Print student's schedule")
    print("4. Print course schedule")
    print("5. Done")
    print("")

def get_option():
    print_menu()
    choice = input("What would you like to do? ")
    while choice not in range(1,6):
        print_menu()
        choice = input("Choice is invalid. What would you like to do? ")
    return choice

def process_students():
    student_dict = {}
    student_info = open(STUDENTS_INPUT,"r")
    for student in student_info:
        info_list = student.split(":")
        new_id = info_list[0]
        first_name = info_list[1]
        last_name = info_list[2]
        course_list = info_list[3:]
        new_student = student.Student(new_id, first_name, last_name, course_list)
        print(new_student.line_for_file())
        student_dict[new_eid] = new_student
    student_info.close()

def process_courses():
    course_dict = {}
    course_info = open(COURSES_INPUT,"r")
    for course in course_info:
        info_list = course.split(";")
        unique_num = info_list[0]
        class_name = info_list[1]
        prof = info_list[2]
        seats = info_list[3]
        capacity = info_list[4]
        new_course = course.Course(unique_num, class_name, prof, seats, capacity)
        course_dict[unique_num] = new_course
    course_info.close()

def print_course_schedule(course_dict):
    for value in course_dict:
        print(value)

def print_student_info(student_dict):
    for value in student_dict:
        print(value)

def get_id():
    eid = input("What is the UT EID? ")
    while eid not in student_dict:
        eid = input("Invalid UT EID. Please re-enter: ")
    return eid

def get_unique():
    unique = input("What is the course unique number? ")
    while unique not in course_dict:
        unique = input("Invalid unique number. Please re-enter: ")
    return unique


def write_updated(filename,dictionary):
    output_file = open(filename,'w')

    for key in dictionary:
        output_file.write(dictionary[key])
    output_file.close()
main()
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\njung\Downloads\MIS 304 Final Project\untitled folder\Nguyen_Calvin_Jung_Nicholas-FP.py", line 132, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\njung\Downloads\MIS 304 Final Project\untitled folder\Nguyen_Calvin_Jung_Nicholas-FP.py", line 24, in main
    process_students()
  File "C:\Users\njung\Downloads\MIS 304 Final Project\untitled folder\Nguyen_Calvin_Jung_Nicholas-FP.py", line 83, in process_students
    new_student = student.Student(new_id, first_name, last_name, course_list)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Student'
>>>
```

I also have the classes used stored in separate files (was required for the program) and have imported the modules containing these classes into main as you can see at the top.

Comment: please, share the courses-sample.txt and students-sample.txt files to recreate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Student'`

Looking at the trace, it seems that it originates from this code:

```
student_info = open(STUDENTS_INPUT,"r")
for student in student_info:
    info_list = student.split(":")
    new_id = info_list[0]
    first_name = info_list[1]
    last_name = info_list[2]
    course_list = info_list[3:]
    new_student = student.Student(new_id, first_name, last_name, course_list)
```

Here you've opened a file. `student_info` is the file, and you iterate over the lines in the file. Each line `student` is a string.

You later call `student.Student(new_id, first_name, last_name, course_list)`, but since `student` is just a string, it naturally does not contain a Student method.